# How to default enable "Automatically manage signing" in Xcode 9 & above

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

Is there some way to default enable "*Automatically manage signing*" in Xcode 9 latest?
I am using the following command to **sign** my `myapp.xcodeproj` **command line** way

```
xcodebuild -project "MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj" -scheme "MyApp" -sdk "iphoneos" -configuration Release PROVISIONING_PROFILE="my_provisioning_profile" DEVELOPMENT_TEAM="team_id"
```

But, I **errors out** saying:

```
Code Signing Error : Provisioning profile does not include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution : team_name Team_ID"
```

However, i dont think any certificates are missing because I well able to do this from *Xcode UI* by selecting "*Automatically manage signing*" & my team ID

**Question:**
Is there some way I can set *Automatic signing* when signing command line?
Tried `CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic` with `xcodebuild` command. But didn't help